# Use encrypted data in a Maven pom

Tags: maven

I know that it is [possible to encrypt a password](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html) and put the encrypted data in the `settings.xml`, so that Maven can access a remote server (for deployment, etc.).

However, in my case, the password is a parameter in the configuration of a third-party plugin.

Normally, the `pom.xml` configuration for this plugin looks like that:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>xxx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-xxx-plugin</artifactId>
            ...
            <configuration>
                <serverAddress>http://myserver</serverAddress>
                <port>4242</port>
                <username>unicorn</username>
                <password>thePassword</password>
                ...
```

But I don't like the idea to set the password in plain text in my `pom.xml`. So I tried to set it as a property (`<password>${encrypted.password}</password>`) and set the encrypted password in the `settings.xml` file, using `mvn --encrypt-password thePassword` command:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myprofile</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- Encrypted passwords -->
            <encrypted.password>{dJXVRKwRiY8HqzhGecHd/MYju/aIEmMT8cnE6MY53uPNr0ro/CAsXSLlgzEjxYeU}</encrypted.password>
        </properties>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work (I suspect that the plugin uses the encrypted password as a "clear" password, and does not try to decrypt it).

Is there a way to make it work? If not, what are the alternative to avoid putting plain text password in `pom.xml` or `settings.xml`?

Thanks.

ps: I'm using Maven 2.2.1, but I can also use Maven 3.0 if needed.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you want to avoid storing of plain text password anywhere or is it just `pom.xml/settings.xml` files that you're concerned about?

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Do you suggest to put the password in plain text in an external properties file, and load this file in the pom? Or is it another idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maven provided the necessary support to encrypt passwords in `settings.xml`, and for plugins to retrieve them. See for example [SqlExecMojo.java](https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sql/SqlExecMojo.java).

Plugins "just" have to use this feature to be more user-friendly with credentials management.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for your answer. I will check with the plugin developers if there is a way for them to implement this feature it in the next version...

Comment: Now for extra credit what If I wanted to use that encrypted project as part of resource filtering instead of in a plugin?

Comment: @nicolas de loof: The above link is asking for credentials.

Comment: The sources have moved to GithHub: https://github.com/mojohaus/sql-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/sql/SqlExecMojo.java

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/echocat/velma

echocat Velma

…is a Master-Password protected password safe for your maven passwords. These passwords are normally stored in .m2/settings.xml and could be protected by a master password in .m2/settings-security.xml. But this way is still dangerous because every person with access to your computer has access to your Master-Password.

Maybe thats what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

up to no I'm also only aware of the password encryption you mentioned. All other encryption must be handled by the plugin itself. Or by a plugin. It may be a solution to put the encryption keys in settings.xml and use the [properties-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to load the properties from the file (or just as inspiration source) and some library like [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) to create your own encryption plugin. You could configure the plugin which properties to decrypt and replace and bind it to an early phase in the maven lifecycle.

I haven't seen something ready to use like this but it looks not too complicated.

Jasypt is also used for the same purpose with the Spring PropertyPlaceholderconfigurer (encrypt date in .properties files).