# How to encrypt password in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, encryption, build

I'm using maven-postman-plugin for sending email to my users after build my project . 
and it works fine but i want to enter my email password encrypted .

My config :

```
  <plugin>
            <groupId>ch.fortysix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-postman-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>send a mail</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>send-mail</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>me</from>
                        <subject>emailSubject</subject>                    
                        <failonerror>false</failonerror>
                        <mailuser>mailUser</mailuser>
                        <mailpassword>123456</mailpassword>
                        <mailhost>mail.navaco.ir</mailhost>
                        <receivers>                            
                            <receiver>m.hoseinnejad@navaco.ir</receiver>
                        </receivers>                      
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I want to enter my password  encrypted like :
{34dsff#W$} not 123456

is there any way ?

Thanks

Comment: If you gives an encrypted password you probably can't connect to the server (account). Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743636/maven-use-encrypted-passwords-in-pom

Comment: Exactly ! . so I'm looking for a way that i can solve this problem .

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743636/maven-use-encrypted-passwords-in-pom) can help you. I hope it will work for the Maven plug-in also.

Comment: Do not put that password in the POM (which is project specific) Put it as a *property* in your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and in the POM refer to that property (e.g. as `${my.mail.password}`)

Comment: Oh thanks . this is the best way

Comment: You should encrypt the passwords in your settings.xml as well...