# Combining Querydsl-jpa and querydsl-sql and code generation

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Here is the thing:

1. I have been using `querydsl-jpa` in my projects and code generation has never been a problem. I use this plugin in `maven`:

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>process</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                       <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. Now, I need to also use `querydsl-sql` and apparently, I can't use the `Q`-generated classes created by `com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor`. Here is the plugin in `maven`:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
           <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>4.2.1</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>export</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <configuration>
                                   <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>
               <jdbcUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase</jdbcUrl>
               <jdbcUser>root</jdbcUser>
               <jdbcPassword></jdbcPassword>                    
               <packageName>com.myproject.domain</packageName>
               <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
           </configuration>
           <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                   <version>8.0.13</version>
               </dependency>
           </dependencies>
       </plugin>
   ```

**THE CHALLENGE**

1. The second plugin above generates `Q`-classes for all schemas in my DBMS (MySql) whereas I have specified the schema to generate `Q`-classes from.
2. How do I specify the username, password and jdbcUrl from a file since I don't want to store sensitive information in the `git` repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my solutions:

1. For challenge one, I haven't found a solution per se but some sort of workaround. I created a user in my DBMS (MySql) that has privileges on the single schema that I am interested in. That way, the user won't be able to generate `Q`-classes for other schemas. So problem one "solved".

**Though I still believe that in the plugin one should be able to specify the schema to be generated. Interestingly enough `<schemaPattern></schemaPattern>` as suggested by @Rober Bain which is also in the `querydsl-sql` documentation does not work.**

2. For challenge two, first you need to create a properties files say `dev.properties` with the needed content

   `jdbc-url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema?nullNamePatternMatchesAll=true`

   `jdbc-user=my_user`

   `jdbc-password=my_password`

   Then, include the following **properties-maven-plugin**

   ```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <files>
                            <file>dev.properties</file> // Reference to properties file
                        </files>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
   ```

... and in your query-dsl plugin ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>export</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jdbcDriver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</jdbcDriver>
                <jdbcUrl>${jdbc-url}</jdbcUrl>
                <jdbcUser>${jdbc-user}</jdbcUser>
                <jdbcPassword>${jdbc-password}</jdbcPassword>
                <packageName>com.myproject.domain</packageName>
                <targetFolder>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Check out this link for more info [Read pom.xml configurations from properties file](http://amrsalah.tech/mwcwp/maven-properties-file/)

Since the above link is down, use [Wayback Online](https://archive.org/web) to see the original web page.

or

Here is a snapshot of the content [image]

and a continuation

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! After hours trying to solve this problem, you answer saved my day.

Comment: @AlexandreMucci I have never understood why `<schemaPattern></schemaPattern>` doesn't work. Looks like it's a bug in the `querydsl-maven` plugin. But restricting the user to a specific schema does the magic.

Comment: Neither I. Are you still using querydsl? I like the tool, but I think it is very complicated to setup. Do you suggest any alternative?

Comment: @AlexandreMucci, yes I am. I prefer it to JPA's Criteria API and JOOQ (not open source). I like querydsl for its syntax for writing dynamic queries. About setup, it's true. It can be a little tricky especially for a first time user but once setup is done, it's such a great tool.

Comment: The link "Read pom.xml configurations from properties file" is outdated. Can you share any updated links?

Comment: Seems the link was brought down. Use https://archive.org/web/ to visit the link but I have updated the answer to include images of the content of that link

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `schemaPattern` within the `configuration` element: "a schema name pattern in LIKE pattern form; must match the schema name as it is stored in the database, multiple can be separated by comma (default: null)" from the [querydsl docs](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch02s03.html#d0e654).
2. While the doesn't do exactly what you're asking for, I believe it's the standard way of solving this problem. [Use encrypted data in a Maven pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299181/use-encrypted-data-in-a-maven-pom).

Comment: 1. Still doesn't work. My schema is called `inuka2` and I have added `<schemaPattern>inuka2</schemaPattern>` but it is still generating for all schemas in my local mysql database.

2. I didn't want to hard code the username, password and jdbcUrl since I don't want to compile applications for test and production environments.